# Set reg query key as variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

i am trying to set a reg query result as variable and unfortunately only the second part of the result is set.

If i run the command:

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications\ /s /f Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_10
```

I get result:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications\Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_10.0.19041.1023_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy

End of search: 1 match(es) found.
```

Now i want to set the "HKLM...xyewy" as a variable running:

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications\ /s /f Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_10') do (set reg=%%i)
```

but the result i am getting back when i echo the variable is "End", which is the first result of the second part of the output. Can someone point to me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('reg query HKLM...') do if not defined reg set "reg=%%i"` You should also have a `setlocal` command at beginning of your Batch file

Comment: This will set "i" as "End of search: 1 match(es) found."

Comment: Not true. It is the _exact same line_ used by Compo in his answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few ideas for you to choose from.

The first uses the method already mentioned in the comments by Aacini, i.e. defines the value from the first line returned:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "KeyRoot=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
Set "KeyBranch=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications"
Set "KeySearch=Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_"
Set "KeyTail="

For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%KeyRoot%\%KeyBranch%" /F "%KeySearch%" /K 2^>NUL') Do If Not Defined KeyTail Set "KeyTail=%%~nxG"
If Not Defined KeyTail GoTo :EOF

Echo %KeyRoot%\%KeyBranch%\%KeyTail%
Pause

EndLocal
```

This ignores the unwanted line based upon the fact it always ends with a period, (`.`):

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "KeyRoot=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
Set "KeyBranch=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications"
Set "KeySearch=Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_"
Set "KeyTail="

For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%KeyRoot%\%KeyBranch%" /F "%KeySearch%" /K 2^>NUL') Do If Not "%%~nxG." == "%%G" Set "KeyTail=%%~nxG"
If Not Defined KeyTail GoTo :EOF

Echo %KeyRoot%\%KeyBranch%\%KeyTail%
Pause

EndLocal
```

This idea pipes to `find.exe` in order to identify the line using a known substring from the target line:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "KeyRoot=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
Set "KeyBranch=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications"
Set "KeySearch=Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_"
Set "KeyTail="

For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%KeyRoot%\%KeyBranch%" /F "%KeySearch%" /K 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%KeyBranch%"') Do Set "KeyTail=%%~nxG"
If Not Defined KeyTail GoTo :EOF

Echo %KeyRoot%\%KeyBranch%\%KeyTail%
Pause

EndLocal
```